# androidx.cardview.widget.CardView was not found in the project or libraries

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview

I can't use the androidx cardview even if I added it to the dependancies. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but it still doesn't work. Here is the gradle file, what am I doing wrong?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.camdrive"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use MaterialCardView?

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:checkable="true">

    ...

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Then in xml-layout use

```
<androidx....
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is I tried making a new project just to test this. I use the androidx cardview after adding the dependency and I still get the error 

`Class referenced in the layout file, androidx.cardview.widget.CardView, was not found in the project or the libraries `

Comment: I update android studio to the newest version (4.1.1) and this error went away.